# How to generate additional line with text to each drop table command using Python or Bash

Tags: python, bash, psql

i have file with sql drops of tables:

```
drop table tab1;
drop table tab2;
drop table tab3;
```

I need to somehow add print before each line, result should be look like:

```
select 'dropping table tab1';
drop table tab1;
select 'dropping table tab2';
drop table tab2;
select 'dropping table tab3';
drop table tab3;
```

Is it possible to somehow add those lines 'select...' using Python or Bash?

Comment: What have you searched for and/or what have you tried?  Edit your question to include a code block containing your attempted code and any errors that you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sed easily:

- first create a backup of your file in case output is not what You want. `cp file file.bak`
- now run `sed -E -i 's/(.*)?;/select \x27\1\x27;\n\1;/' file`
- if result is not what you expected then restore your file `mv file.bak file`

`-E` to enable regex, `-i` to enable in place edit.
`(.*)?;` means match everything until you reach first `;` and place everything matched in a group.
`x27` is `'`. so `select \x27` becomes `select '`.
`\1` is the group we matched before.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash `while read loop` and parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r f l ; do
    printf "select 'dropping %s\n%s %s\n" "${l//;/\';}" "$f" "$l"
done <src.sql
```

Using python and some string replacements:

```
with open("src.sql") as sql_file:
    for line in sql_file:
        line=line.replace(";\n", "';")
        orig=line
        line=line.replace("drop", "select 'dropping")
        print(f'{line}\n{orig}')
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{orig=$0; $1="select '\''dropping"; sub(/;$/,"'\'';"); $0=$0"\n"orig; }1' src.sql
```

Redirect the output from any of these options into a new file.